# Zend Framework 1 database abstraction: implementation of USE INDEX/FORCE INDEX for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, abstraction, zf1

I try to FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`PRIMARY`) and haven't found а definite answer whether this was implemented in ZF1 and decided to ask here: Was this implemented and can you give usage example?https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/489

I tried using the method like this:

```
$this->db->select()->forceIndex('PRIMARY')->from('somefield')->..
```

But this returns an error:

```
Unrecognized method 'forceIndex()'
```

And I am still not sure whether I try to use it incorrectly or it wasn't implemented at all.

Comment: Usually use/force should not be used.  Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

you can use join() and where() functions to do this kind of task :

```
$select = $this->select()->from(array('c' => 'cities'),array('*'));
    $select->distinct();
    $select->join(array('l' => 'cities_lang'), 'c.id=l.city_id', array());
    $select->where('l.locale_code = ?', $locale);
    $select->where('l.city_name LIKE ?', $like);
    $select->order('(l.city_name = ' . $db->quote($query) . ') DESC');
    $select->limit($perpage, ($page-1)*$perpage);

    $this->fetchAll($select);
```